# Prove that $\exists X_0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}=\{X_{0}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $I_{n}=[a_{n},b_{n}$] for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $I_{n+1} \subseteq I_{n}$ also let $\inf\{b_{n}-a_{n}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}=0.$  Prove that exists $X_0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}=\{X_{0}\}.$

I've tried to prove that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n} \neq \emptyset$ with the nested interval theorem and then take 2 points and show these points are the same, but I can't. HELP! :(

Comment: Google "Cantor (Intersection) Theorem" ...in the real line.

Comment: You've started your proof correctly! It is possible to show that the two points will be the same (or else the claim would be false). Note that you haven't yet used the assumption that $\inf\{b_n - a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} = 0$. What does this imply about the difference between the two points you picked in the intersection?

Answer (score 1):

$I_{n+1}\subset I_n$ means $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\subset[a_n,b_n]$ and thus $a_{n+1}\geqslant a_n$ and $b_{n+1}\leqslant b_n$ for all $n\geqslant 1$. $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is an increasing sequence, $(b_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a decreasing sequence, thus $(b_n-a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a decreasing sequence, its limit is $\inf_{n\geqslant 1}(b_n-a_n)=0$. Thus the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are adjacent and converge towards the same limit $\ell$, and $\ell$ is such that $a_n\leqslant\ell\leqslant b_n$ for all $n\geqslant 1$, this means that $\displaystyle\ell\in\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}I_n$ and thus the intersection is not empty. Now if $\displaystyle\ell,\ell'\in\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}I_n$, then $\ell,\ell'\in I_n$ for all $n\geqslant 1$ and thus $|\ell-\ell'|\leqslant b_n-a_n$ for all $n\geqslant 1$. Letting $n\rightarrow +\infty$ gives $\ell=\ell'$.

Answer (score 1):

We know $\cap_{n=1}^\infty I_n \neq \emptyset$. Suppose there are two points, $x_1$ and $x_2$ in this set. Clearly, $a_n\leq x_1 \leq b_n$ and $a_n\leq x_2 \leq b_n$ for all $n$. Hence, $|x_1-x_2|\leq b_n-a_n$ for all $n$. If $x_1 \neq x_2$, then $|x_1-x_2|>0$. Where's the contradiction? Or you can just prove that $x_1=x_2$ directly using squeeze theorem.